# why is not saving to SQL data base from html form? it does not show any error messages

Tags: php, html, css, sql, database

I tried many ways if I insert data to my data base without the 
from method it works but with the form and it's method is not working and it doesn't show any error. I don't see any message seems like the code doesn't exist. the connection is good and the name of the table is fine. I am trying to save some data before to implement more code like validation password check and more but if it doesn't save the data how I am going to implement validations. I used the numbers of my serve because it could not be connect with localhost name.

```
       <?php
       session_start(); 
       $_SESSION['message'] = "";
       $host = "localhost:3308";
       $user = "root";
       $password = "";
       $database = "accounts";
        $connect = mysqli_connect($host, $user, 
        $password,$database); //open the connection.

         if(!$connect){

         die("cannot connect to database 
         field:".mysqli_connect_error());
                   }
            else
            {
         `enter code here`echo "Database is connected". " 
    <br/>";
       if(isset($_POST['create'])){
       session_start();

        $userName = $_POST['username'];
    `enter code here`$email = $_POST['email'];
    $pasword = $_POST['pasword'];
    $avatar= $_POST['avatar'];

        $sql = "INSERT INTO new_table  ( 
        username,email,password,avatar)
        VALUES ( 
   '$userName','$email','$pasword','$avatar')";
        if(mysqli_query($connect, $sql)) {
        $_SESSION['message']= "creted";
      }
else{
     $_SESSION['message']= "not created";
     }
}
else {
    $_SESSION['message']= "Enter valid data";
}
   //my html form
    <form action="conectingDB.php"  method = "post">
<form action="conectingDB.php"  method = "post">

     <header>
     <h3></h3>
     </header>
   <br /><br />
   <div><?php $_SESSION['message'] ?></div>

      <input type="text" name="username" placeholder= 
"username" required /><br /><br />

     <input type="email" name="email" placeholder = "email" 
 required /> <br /><br />

     <input type="password" name="password" 
  placeholder="pasword" required /> <br /><br />

     <div class = "avatar"><label>Select your avatar:
     <input type= "text" name="avatar" ></label></div>

      <input type="button" value="create account"   
       name="create" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest one more files in your directory with the name "conectingDB.php" and in this file insert the insert command with the connection to the database.
replace the

```
<input type = "button" value = "create account" name = "create" />
```

for this

```
<button type = "submit" value = "create account" name = "create"></button>
```

Comment: thank you actually that was my error now it is working perfectly.